# MySQL stops working on AWS ec2 instance periodically for no reason

Tags: linux, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

I run a development server on AWS which has worked perfectly fine without a hitch.  Recently, periodically the mysql server starts to not work.  I then type in

```
service mysqld restart
```

which yields an error message

```
MySQL Daemon failed to start.
```

Now if I stop the instance and then start it, and then restart the server from the command line, everything works fine (this annoyingly forced me to re-edit my zone file due to changed ip addresses, but I've read that a reboot won't get rid of ip addresses).  But are there any clues as to why this wouldn't be working?

Here are a few lines from var/log/mysqld.log that I cannot make heads or tails of.

```
130613 23:12:21 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
130613 23:12:21 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
130613 23:12:21 InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
130613 23:12:21 InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
130613 23:12:21 InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.5
130613 23:12:21 InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
130613 23:12:21 InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
130613 23:12:21 InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
InnoDB: The first specified data file ./ibdata1 did not exist:
InnoDB: a new database to be created!
130613 23:12:21  InnoDB: Setting file ./ibdata1 size to 10 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130613 23:12:22  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile0 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile0 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
130613 23:12:23  InnoDB: Log file ./ib_logfile1 did not exist: new to be created
InnoDB: Setting log file ./ib_logfile1 size to 5 MB
InnoDB: Database physically writes the file full: wait...
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer not found: creating new
InnoDB: Doublewrite buffer created
InnoDB: 127 rollback segment(s) active.
InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables
InnoDB: Foreign key constraint system tables created
130613 23:12:24  InnoDB: Waiting for the background threads to start
130613 23:12:25 InnoDB: 5.5.31 started; log sequence number 0
130613 23:12:25 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '0.0.0.0'; port: 3306
130613 23:12:25 [Note]   - '0.0.0.0' resolves to '0.0.0.0';
130613 23:12:25 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '0.0.0.0'.
130613 23:12:25 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
130613 23:12:25 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '5.5.31'  socket: '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
130614  6:08:52 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Normal shutdown

130614  6:08:53 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
```

I read at other posts on stackexchange that sometimes this can be due to disk size limitations.  df - h says

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/xvda1            7.9G  1.7G  6.2G  22% /
tmpfs                 298M     0  298M   0% /dev/shm
```

Anyone have any idea what else I should be hunting for?

Comment: Have you considered RDS so you don't have to manage your own MySQL instance?

Answer (score 1):

First, you have to backup your databases:

```
cp -r /var/lib/mysql /tmp/mysql_backup
```

Then, remove the file from `/var/lib/mysql`.

```
rm -rf ibdata1
```

Now restart the mysql server.

```
/etc/init.d/mysqld start
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Nitpicks: 1. `rm -rf` is overkill, do stick to plain `rm` for removing single files, use `rm -r` for directories. Add `-f` only if you cannot be bothered lifting the write protection from many files in the tree. 2. `cp -r` is OK, but you use all file metadata. `cp -a` (or better yet, `rsync`) is almost always preferable.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using micro or small instances, mysql database running websites can can put a pretty big load on your VMs memory which will end up constantly crashing your mysql server.

Consider using **RDS** which might be more expensive or at least ec2 **t2.medium** to save money and still run fine.

For IPs, you'd have to allocate your instance **elastic** IP which will stay with your instance till you get rid of it, you won't have to pay for the IP as long as you're using it.

Comment: Check with dmesg if MySQL was OOM killed. You can add a swap if you don't want to upgrade to bigger instance with more RAM at the expense of performance.

Comment: Before suggesting a RDS it should be noted that this costs nearly $600 a month i made that mistake and thought i would share.

Answer (score 0):

The mysql instance gets killed if you are using t2.micro instance which has around only 1GB of memory. If you do ps -ef | grep apache, you can can see numbers of apache instances running . A high number of apache instances would force server to kill mysql when it is running low on memory.

Answer (score 0):

Install monit to monitor Apache. When the load goes up, Monit restarts Apache gracefully and everything keeps on working.